# VBA, Time Difference, 24 hour clock

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to get time differences.

Say I have 4 columns: Start day, start time, end day, end time. I would like to get the difference of the start day and time with the end day and time.

Problem is, times may be 20:00 on T, and 02:00 on T+1 , giving me a difference of 18 hours. When it should be 6 hours.

I need some help calculating the true time difference. Whether using VBA or Formula.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

```
03/02/2016  6:29:34 03/02/2016  9:31:39
03/15/2016  23:17:51    03/15/2016  23:25:36
03/16/2016  2:15:53 03/16/2016  2:15:58
03/15/2016  20:45:19    03/15/2016  21:09:07
03/15/2016  20:45:25    03/15/2016  20:58:59
03/16/2016  3:12:21 03/16/2016  3:12:30
03/16/2016  3:33:19 03/16/2016  6:07:58
03/16/2016  3:40:13 03/16/2016  6:12:50
03/16/2016  3:47:05 03/16/2016  6:16:59
03/15/2016  22:18:51    03/15/2016  22:18:57
03/15/2016  20:51:14    03/15/2016  20:51:19
03/15/2016  20:51:23    03/15/2016  22:07:25
03/15/2016  20:52:46    03/16/2016  2:01:57
03/15/2016  20:52:48    03/15/2016  22:44:39
03/16/2016  1:31:43 03/16/2016  1:35:18
03/15/2016  20:55:37    03/16/2016  2:13:30
03/15/2016  20:55:03    03/15/2016  20:58:56
03/15/2016  20:53:37    03/16/2016  2:11:34
03/15/2016  20:56:27    03/15/2016  20:56:36
03/15/2016  20:56:40    03/15/2016  22:43:39
03/15/2016  20:57:02    03/16/2016  4:06:36
03/15/2016  20:57:12    03/15/2016  21:01:35
03/15/2016  20:57:21    03/15/2016  22:17:34
03/15/2016  20:59:01    03/15/2016  22:44:28
03/15/2016  20:59:03    03/15/2016  22:22:59
03/15/2016  20:59:43    03/15/2016  23:06:02
03/15/2016  21:01:38    03/15/2016  21:01:43
03/15/2016  21:01:47    03/15/2016  22:55:07
03/15/2016  21:09:11    03/15/2016  22:19:53
03/15/2016  20:45:32    03/15/2016  20:52:44
03/15/2016  20:45:38    03/15/2016  20:59:39
03/15/2016  20:45:44    03/15/2016  20:51:00
03/15/2016  20:45:45    03/15/2016  21:30:36
03/15/2016  21:30:40    03/15/2016  21:30:46
03/15/2016  20:45:51    03/15/2016  20:45:55
03/15/2016  20:45:51    03/15/2016  20:45:55
03/15/2016  21:30:40    03/15/2016  23:15:32
03/16/2016  2:16:00 03/16/2016  2:24:15
03/16/2016  4:29:20 03/16/2016  4:29:24
03/16/2016  4:29:56 03/16/2016  4:41:31
02/04/2016  5:03:17 02/04/2016  5:03:21
03/16/2016  4:37:32 03/16/2016  5:44:57
03/16/2016  4:41:35 03/16/2016  5:45:41
03/16/2016  4:46:39 03/16/2016  5:49:00
03/16/2016  4:52:32 03/16/2016  5:57:40
03/16/2016  4:56:47 03/16/2016  6:06:33
03/16/2016  5:00:58 03/16/2016  6:06:29
03/16/2016  5:05:07 03/16/2016  6:05:03
03/16/2016  5:09:13 03/16/2016  6:08:24
03/15/2016  20:45:58    03/15/2016  20:53:34
03/16/2016  1:09:17 03/16/2016  1:24:15
03/16/2016  3:17:21 03/16/2016  3:27:41
03/15/2016  22:44:37    03/15/2016  22:44:41
03/16/2016  2:16:06 03/16/2016  2:23:46
03/02/2016  6:21:32 03/02/2016  6:21:41
03/16/2016  2:07:14 03/16/2016  2:09:40
03/16/2016  2:16:13 03/16/2016  2:16:17
03/16/2016  3:16:16 03/16/2016  3:25:21
03/16/2016  3:16:16 03/16/2016  3:17:20
03/16/2016  3:26:01 03/16/2016  3:34:23
03/16/2016  2:16:19 03/16/2016  2:23:03
03/15/2016  23:08:19    03/16/2016  0:47:27
03/15/2016  20:45:58    03/15/2016  20:52:42
03/16/2016  2:07:21 03/16/2016  2:07:26
03/16/2016  2:16:20 03/16/2016  2:31:01
03/16/2016  0:30:43 03/16/2016  0:30:49
03/15/2016  20:45:58    03/15/2016  20:57:18
03/15/2016  20:45:59    03/15/2016  20:56:57
03/15/2016  20:45:59    03/15/2016  20:56:24
03/15/2016  20:45:59    03/15/2016  20:55:34
03/15/2016  20:46:04    03/15/2016  20:54:59
03/15/2016  20:46:05    03/15/2016  20:50:57
03/16/2016  0:11:30 03/16/2016  1:14:54
03/16/2016  0:16:00 03/16/2016  1:16:38
03/16/2016  0:20:47 03/16/2016  1:12:29
03/16/2016  0:25:45 03/16/2016  1:09:22
03/16/2016  0:30:14 03/16/2016  1:02:42
03/16/2016  0:30:53 03/16/2016  0:31:00
03/15/2016  20:51:00    03/15/2016  20:57:08
03/15/2016  22:17:53    03/15/2016  22:32:45
03/15/2016  20:51:04    03/15/2016  20:51:08
03/16/2016  2:02:01 03/16/2016  2:02:05
03/16/2016  4:09:03 03/16/2016  4:20:56
03/16/2016  4:08:45 03/16/2016  4:08:49
03/16/2016  4:08:55 03/16/2016  4:21:55
03/16/2016  4:19:51 03/16/2016  5:43:01
03/16/2016  4:21:39 03/16/2016  5:13:21
03/16/2016  4:23:44 03/16/2016  5:09:15
03/16/2016  4:25:47 03/16/2016  4:37:24
03/16/2016  4:18:50 03/16/2016  4:49:45
03/16/2016  4:33:38 03/16/2016  5:31:13
03/16/2016  4:34:54 03/16/2016  5:17:24
03/16/2016  3:17:44 03/16/2016  4:23:21
03/16/2016  4:23:25 03/16/2016  4:23:29
03/16/2016  3:21:49 03/16/2016  3:32:58
03/16/2016  3:24:59 03/16/2016  3:37:11
03/16/2016  3:27:35 03/16/2016  3:38:37
03/16/2016  6:20:29 03/16/2016  6:20:33
03/16/2016  2:04:35 03/16/2016  2:10:40
03/16/2016  2:06:32 03/16/2016  3:31:43
03/16/2016  5:58:19 03/16/2016  5:58:23
03/16/2016  2:07:39 03/16/2016  2:19:36
03/15/2016  23:01:00    03/15/2016  23:01:47
03/15/2016  22:52:27    03/15/2016  22:52:58
03/15/2016  22:57:25    03/15/2016  22:58:18
03/15/2016  22:49:37    03/15/2016  22:50:25
03/15/2016  22:49:58    03/15/2016  22:50:30
03/15/2016  22:49:46    03/15/2016  22:50:18
03/16/2016  1:58:35 03/16/2016  1:59:12
03/16/2016  1:58:41 03/16/2016  1:59:08
03/15/2016  22:53:27    03/15/2016  22:53:57
03/16/2016  1:58:48 03/16/2016  1:59:08
03/16/2016  1:58:54 03/16/2016  1:59:03
03/16/2016  1:59:00 03/16/2016  1:59:19
03/16/2016  1:58:26 03/16/2016  1:59:03
03/15/2016  23:00:43    03/15/2016  23:01:10
03/15/2016  22:52:44    03/15/2016  22:53:32
03/16/2016  1:59:01 03/16/2016  1:59:16
03/15/2016  23:02:06    03/15/2016  23:02:34
03/15/2016  23:03:35    03/15/2016  23:04:06
03/15/2016  22:56:42    03/15/2016  22:57:43
03/15/2016  22:57:54    03/15/2016  22:59:00
03/15/2016  23:06:21    03/15/2016  23:06:47
03/15/2016  23:00:03    03/15/2016  23:00:52
03/15/2016  23:08:57    03/15/2016  23:09:21
03/16/2016  1:59:01 03/16/2016  2:01:58
03/15/2016  23:01:34    03/15/2016  23:02:03
03/15/2016  23:00:28    03/15/2016  23:01:00
03/15/2016  23:09:58    03/15/2016  23:10:12
03/16/2016  8:02:06 03/16/2016  8:04:45
03/16/2016  7:04:54 03/16/2016  7:05:18
```

Comment: U need to consider the date part of the difference along with time part. Theway excel handles datetime is little complicated until someone fully understands.

Answer (score 0):

So if your columns start at A1 then:

```
=(C1+D1)-(A1+B1)
```

This only works if they are true date/time and not text.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Make sure you use a custom format on column E of `[hh]:mm:ss` this will make it work if the hours are greater than 24.

Comment: getting #VALUE as a fill down. Seems to work for the first calcuatiion though, very odd.

Comment: Tried :`=SUM(D2,E2)-SUM(B2,C2)` was able to fill down, but only works if the days are the same. Not T and T + 1.

Comment: I would need to see your data

Comment: do you have an email where I can send it to? Or shall I post a pic?

Comment: post a pic, then if someone else has a better solution they have the info also.

Comment: Actually post the data itself as text in the Original post that way I do not need to recreate and can just copy paste.

Comment: let me know if this is sufficient.

Comment: @Jonathan the formula worked for me.  See edit.  You may need to format the cells with a custom format of `[hh]:mm:ss`

Comment: Not sure, this is bizarre, I am getting #VALUE still after the first cell.

Comment: Then some of your dates or time or both are text not actual date/time.  Try `=((--C1)+(--D1))-((--A1)+(--B1))`

Comment: Change your format to general on your date and time columns, did it change to a number or did it remain a date?  If it remained a date then it is text and needs to be changed to a number, there are many methods online to do this with formulas.  If they change to numbers then I have no idea why it is not working. Sorry

Comment: The Start and End times turned into Numbers. However dates stayed the same except for the 1st row. (1st row changed to numbers for dates)

Comment: There ya go.  Your dates need to be changed from text to numbers.  Put this in an empty column: `=IFERROR(DATEVALUE(A1),A1)` and copy down, then copy and paste just the values back into column A.  Do this for Column C also.

Comment: the values still remain as dates lol. Except for that first row.

Comment: seems like these are strings not actual dates in my file.

Comment: Then you need to figure a way to make them dates.  Try this formula instead of the last one in a blank column `=IFERROR(DATEVALUE(TRIM(A1)),A1) ` If that does not work I am out of ideas.